# not getting expected parameter when selectOneMenu item is selected

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Hi I have the following in my HTML:

```
<p:selectOneMenu  value="#{lottoCheckerBean.selectedPowerBallDrawingDate}"  >
                        <p:ajax update="powerBallDrawings"  listener="#{lottoCheckerBean.handleDrawDateSelection}" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{lottoCheckerBean.powerBallDrawingDates}"  />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

The relavent section of my bean code follows:

```
 public void setSelectedPowerBallDrawingDate(String newSelectedPowerBallDate) {


    this.selectedPowerBallDrawingDate = newSelectedPowerBallDate;
}
```

The ajax tag causes a call to the setSelectedPowerBallDrawingDate(String newSelectedPowerBallDate) as expected.  But the value of newSelectedPowerBallDate is the empty string.  Not the expected selected value of the dropdown.

The source for the selectOneMenu is a List<String>

List.  Does this require a converter?

Comment: Do you mean that, in handleDrawDateSelection the value of selectedPowerBallDrawingDate never changes and is always equal to "" String ? Would you please replace <p:ajax> with <f:ajax> and see what happens ?

Comment: Actually it is the argument to the setSelectedPowerBallDrawingDate that is "" when it is called.   This causes the value of selectedPowerBallDrawingDate to be "" when handleDrawDateSelection is called.  

Thank you for your response.  I did try your suggestion.  Id did not change the results 

I did find the problem.  The selectOneMenu was outside of any form.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Laabidi Raissi for his suggestion.  The answer, however was that my selectOneMenu fell outside of the form.  Moving the form tags so they enclosed the dropdown solved the problem.